# Is the union of intersections of all combinations of sets equal to the intersection of unions of the combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Given $n$ sets $A_1 \ldots A_n$, and $1 \lt k \lt n$, is it true that the union of the intersections of all the combinations of $k$ sets is equal to the intersection of the unions of the same combinations?
If yes, how to prove it?

For example, for $n = 3$ and $k = 2$, I have verified that:

$$(A_1 \cap A_2) \cup (A_1 \cap A_3) \cup (A_2 \cap A_3) = (A_1 \cup A_2) \cap (A_1 \cup A_3) \cap (A_2 \cup A_3)$$

Comment: Think of 'membership bits': what combinations of memberships in $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ — written as a three-bit table, if that makes things easier for the reasoning — would cause an element to be in the set on the LHS of your equation? What about the set on the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first set consists of all the elements that are in at least $k$ of the $A_i$

The second set consists of all the elements that are in every union of $k$ $A_i$. So an element is not in the set if we can find $k$ $A_i$ that do not contain it, that is, the second set consists of all the elements that are in at least $n-k+1$ $A_i$

Comment: Isn't it "if we can find $k$ $A_i$ that do not contain it", i.e. an element is not in the set if it is contained in maximum $n-k$ $A_i$, and thus to be in the set it must be contained in at least $n-k+1$ sets?

Comment: 100% correct, thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: You modified the answer, but I think what it actually should be is: "So an element is not in the set if we can find $k$ $A_i$ that do not contain it, that is, the second set consists of all the elements that are in at least $n−k+1$ $A_i$", which also applies to my example, because $2 = k = n - k + 1 = 3 - 2 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: I have proposed an edit according to the above comment.