# A property implying union-closed sets conjecture condition

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, solution-verification, conjectures

Given a union-closed family $\mathcal{F}$ of $n=\vert \mathcal{F} \vert$ sets, $n$ odd, and its family $\mathit{J}(\mathcal{F})$ of $m = \vert\mathit{J}(\mathcal{F})\vert$ basis sets (or $\cup$-irreducible sets, also called generators), and defined $\mathcal{F_a} = \{A \in \mathcal{F}: a \in A \}$, the union-closed sets conjecture states that there exists at least one element $a \in U(\mathcal{F})$ such that $\vert \mathcal{F_a} \vert \ge \frac{n}{2}$.

We furtherly define $\mathit{J_a}(\mathcal{F}) = \{A \in \mathit{J}(\mathcal{F}) : a \in A \}$.

I am kindly asking for a verification of the below proof of the following:

**Statement**

If $\exists a$ such that $\vert\mathit{J_a}(\mathcal{F})\vert \ge m-\Bigl\lfloor\log_2{\frac{n+1}{2}}\Bigr\rfloor$, then $\vert \mathcal{F_a} \vert \ge \frac{n}{2}$.

**Proof**

With $k = \frac{n+1}{2}$, $A_i \in \mathcal{F}, i = 1 \ldots n$:

$$\bigcup_{1 \le i_1 \lt \ldots \lt i_k \le n} A_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k} = \bigcap_{1 \le i_1 \lt \ldots \lt i_k \le n} A_{i_1} \cup \ldots \cup A_{i_k} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

This is because the LHS contains all elements that are in at least $k$ of the $A_i$ and the RHS contains all elements that are in at least $n-k+1$ of the $A_i$ (because for each element that does not belong to the RHS we can find $k$ $A_i$ that do not contain it and thus it is in maximum $n-k$ of the $A_i$) and note that in our case $k=n-k+1$ (see also [the answer to this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3638979/573047)).

If we define $J_i \in J(\mathcal{F}), i = 1 \ldots m$, then, since the family is union-closed, each union term on the RHS can be expressed as the union of at least $\lfloor\log_2{k}\rfloor + 1$ of them. This implies that:

$$\bigcap_{1 \le i_1 \lt \ldots \lt i_{\lfloor\log_2{k}\rfloor + 1}\le m} J_{i_1} \cup \ldots \cup J_{i_{\lfloor\log_2{k}\rfloor + 1}} \subseteq \bigcap_{1 \le i_1 \lt \ldots \lt i_k \le n} A_{i_1} \cup \ldots \cup A_{i_k} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

(we can compute the intersection of the RHS and the LHS and see that it is equal to the LHS).
Now the LHS is the set of all $a \in U(\mathcal{F})$ such that $\vert\mathit{J_a}(\mathcal{F})\vert \ge m-\lfloor\log_2{k}\rfloor-1+1 = m-\lfloor\log_2{k}\rfloor$, for the same argument applied to \eqref{1} above, and thus if it is not empty the RHS will be not empty too.

Is this correct? And explained clearly?
Thank you.

Comment: Let $[n]=\{1,2,3,\cdots n\}$. Isn't the family generated by the basis $\mathcal B=\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, [31]\}$ and $a=31$ a counterexample to your property?

Comment: No it isn't. I have put the requirement that the number of sets be odd (because it can be shown that if there is a counterexample to the union closed sets conjecture with an even number of sets than there is also a counterxample with an odd number of sets), while in your case there are 8 sets. But anyway in any case, I have required just one $a$ satisfying the property (and $1$, $2$ and $3$ satisfy it), not all of them.

Comment: My bad. I thought $n$ was the number of elements in the universe. By " I have required just one $a$ satisfying the property " do you mean that only one $a$ satisfies $\vert\mathit{J_a}(\mathcal{F})\vert \ge m-\Bigl\lfloor\log_2{\frac{n+1}{2}}\Bigr\rfloor$ or that among all $a$'s satisfying the above, one of them satisfies $\mathcal F_a\geq\frac{|\mathcal F|}{2}$?

Comment: More precisely, as I have written in the statement, we need at least one $a$ satisfying the condition, because that element will then belong to half or more of the sets. All elements satisfying the condition will then belong to half or more of the sets, but one is enough for the union closed sets conjecture.

Comment: I see. The argument you have given looks correct to me. And it is pretty neat and beautiful!